# ".gitlab-ci.yml" pipeline returns an error `downstream project could not be found`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Path to all projects is valid. I can confirm this because the code below works and runs a child pipeline:

```
  stage: multi_project_test
  trigger:
    project: "my_organization/my_group/project_1"
    strategy: depend
```

But the following code results in `downstream project could not be found`:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - multi_project_test
  - deploy


include:
  - local: ".gitlab-ci-common.yml"

test:
  extends: .test_stage_common
  script:
    - poetry install -vv
    - !reference [.test_stage_common, script]

downstream_pipelines:
  stage: multi_project_test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT:
          [
            my_organization/my_group/project_1,
            my_organization/my_group/project_2,
            my_organization/my_group/project_3,
            my_organization/my_group/project_4,
          ]
  trigger:
    project: $DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT
    strategy: depend
  variables:
    PIPELINE_TYPE: "multi-project-pipeline"
```

Why the error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: in GitLab 15.3 (Released August 2022) [variables are now supported](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/) in `trigger:project`.

---

Variables are allowed in many places, however `trigger:project` does not support use of variables. There is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/249583) tracking enabling this feature to work for `trigger:project`.

As of GitLab 15.0, variables can be used in the following places in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

| Definition | Can be expanded? | Expansion place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `after_script` | yes | Script execution shell |
| `artifacts:name` | yes | Runner |
| `before_script` | yes | Script execution shell |
| `cache:key` | yes | Runner |
| `environment:name` | yes | GitLab |
| `environment:url` | yes | GitLab |
| `except:variables:[]` | no | n/a |
| `image` | yes | Runner |
| `include` | yes | GitLab |
| `only:variables:[]` | no | n/a |
| `resource_group` | yes | GitLab |
| `rules:if` | no | n/a |
| `script` | yes | Script execution shell |
| `services:[]:name` | yes | Runner |
| `services:[]` | yes | Runner |
| `tags` | yes | GitLab |
| `variables` | yes | GitLab/Runner |

For a full reference, including other files/places variables can be used, see the documentation: [where variables can be used](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html).

As a workaround, you could trigger the projects in a `script:` instead, which [should provide the same effect](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/10126#note_380343695).

```yaml
trigger:
  image: alpine
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT_ID: ["1234", "5678"]
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=main "https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline"
```

Comment: Note that this has been [fixed in Gitlab 15.3](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/92346).

But I did find this helpful because I'm on an earlier version. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing @AndrewO -- I've updated the answer to include this.